# PHP - Creating custom variable for template

Tags: php, regex

I don't know exactly how to say this, I'll use an example.

```
//[$var:Username|n] will print username with n length
$myText = 'The participants are [$var:Username|10], [$var:Username|8], and [$var:Username|6]';
$username = array('Alexandrite', 'Maximillian', 'Angelina');
$result = someFunction('[$var:Username|n]', $username, $myText);
echo $result;
//The participants are Alexandrit, Maximill, and Angeli
```

Any idea how to do this? Maybe using preg_replace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm interested to know why you would even need to do this.  Regardless:

```
preg_replace_callback('/\[\$var:Username\|(\d+)\]/', function ($match)
    use (&$count, $username
) {
    return substr($username[$count++], 0, $match[1]);
}, $myText);
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to create a text editor where user can create a template using those custom variable, then at the next step they choose the variable value, then as final result I need this function to put the chosen value to the template. Ah, the result I get is "The participants are , Maximill, and Angeli", Alexandrit is missing.

Comment: Ah, I found the problem, first $count variable is empty not 0. Just need to set it to 0. This really helped me since I don't even know preg_replace_callback exists. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @v1n_vampire ah sorry, I should have added `$count = 0`.  I did that in my test code